# Use IIS for debugging in visual studio, without an external directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, iis, 64-bit, virtual-directory

I've a 64 bits web application(not 32 or any cpu)(because we most of used dll which are needed to be in 64 bit because they are used another process that need at least 5GB of RAM).

I need to debug it in IIS, so I put "Local IIS Web Server" with a Virtual directory.

The problem is that we use CSS files which are used for more than 30 others website, and we have a formal prohibition of making any change in this file. AND they reference ressource in the CSS with "/assets/.../...", so if I put this in a subfolder, all css point to a wrong path(mostly for images).

Is there a way to make that visual studio uses `http://localhost:9999`(for example?)

Because If I put this, I got an error message when I try to create the virtual directory:
[image]

**EDIT**

If I create the site in IIS, the virtual directory creation works, but when I launch the website, I got an error message of visual studio:(yeah, I changed my mind for the 7777 port, IIS is configured the same):
[image]
Any idea?

Comment: Have you created an IIS website with a binding for port 9999?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create new site in IIS and set port to 9999, then try again.

More info:
[Create a Web Site (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772350%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: In fact I already tried this, but I had error at launch, I updated the main subject with those additional info

Comment: You must configure your site in IIS, set application pool and etc. Set show error localy to view errors in browser. Common error in 64 bit OS is set "Enable 32 bit applications" in Advanced settings, because you can have some 32 bit dll`s.

Comment: I've made an huge error, I let the application pool in the default .Net 2.x :/. Works better with .Net 4.x. Thanks for the help